# Sleep/Restart causing a black screen forcing a hard power off

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, monterey

I just purchased a MacBook Pro early-2015. I updated the operating system to Monterey 12.6.1 and now whenever the laptop goes to sleep, I'm forced to hold the power button to hard shut off and then immediately press the power button to turn it back on. This seems to be the case whenever I restart it as well. The screen is just black with nothing visible. The caps lock button still lights up, as well as the backlight on the keyboard.

I've done a little troubleshooting and tried resetting the SMC and the NVRAM/PRAM. Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: what are your sleep settings, or just the lid close

Comment: There might be some start item not starting correctly, causing the system to wait.  Did you also try a [safe start](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mh21245/mac)?

Comment: @Ruskes Turn display off after: 2mins, slightly dim the display while on battery power, show battery status in menu bar.

Comment: @not2savvy I did try a safe start as well. It did not fix the issue.

Comment: Let's try for more details. Open the Terminal app, then type **pmset -g** and post the output here